# offline app and sync with server - Sammy framework

Tags: javascript

I need to create a web application that must be used offline. Users will use tablets to use it. The way it works is as follows:

1. The first time users get the tablets, they will access the web application because they will be connected to the internet, so the app should be downloaded to the tablet (locally).
2. From then on, they will have to be able to interact with the app in offline mode. They will complete a few forms, the framework used should let me implement some logic to decide which forms should be displayed and when users send the forms, they should be stored in the tablets until users arrive at home and they can connect to a WIFI.
3. When the tablet connects to a WIFI, it must send the forms to a remote server to parse the information.

I've been told that there is a framework called Sammy JS that can do this, but I would like to know if you know other solutions that could meet these requirements. Any comments will be wellcome.

I guess that everything must be done in javascript so it can work offline.